# How to add the Java Path as an environment variable bash_profile on Mac

Tags: java, pyspark

Here is how my bash_profile looks:

```sh
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/henilshelat/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/henilshelat/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/henilshelat/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/henilshelat/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei23V.png)
And here is the location of my Java_Home: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`

How and where do I update the path to Java_home?

Answer (score 0):

In *.bash_profile* you just have to insert

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```